# Rest Assured 3.1.0 Issue Request Body getting trimmed internally if beyond certain character limit

Tags: xml, automation, rest-assured

I am trying to invoke post request via Rest assured 3.1.0 library request body string which is an xml, gets trimmed internally, hence causing failure in request call. The XML has 3996 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try using header Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: Used the suggestion @AlexKaramfilov but landed into another problem. Getting this error Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Transfer-encoding header already present. **RequestContent.class** process method has this code `if (this.overwrite) {
                request.removeHeaders("Transfer-Encoding");
                request.removeHeaders("Content-Length");
            } else {
                if (request.containsHeader("Transfer-Encoding")) {
                    throw new ProtocolException("Transfer-encoding header already present");
                }`